# SELECT Column_B FROM tableA where Column_A = ? AND SELECT Column C from tableB where Column B = Column B from table 1?

Tags: mysql

So I have a database with two tables in it.

**dept_emp table:**

```
emp_no | dept_no
----------------
001    | 008
002    | 006
etc.   | etc.
```

**departments table:**

```
dept_no | dept_name
--------------------
d001    | Customer Service
d002    | Development
etc.    | etc.
```

In my API I'd like to build a single request to the database that can combine both of these lines of code:

```
"SELECT dept_no FROM dept_emp WHERE emp_no = ?"
```

then

```
"SELECT dept_name FROM departments WHERE dept_no = (the previously grabbed dept_no)"
```

I know how to do things similar (but less complicated) than this in one query with JOIN and HAVING, but syntax is giving me a hard time here. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Join the tables on the `dept_no` column.

Comment: You can also simply put the first query where you wrote `the previously grabbed dept_no`

Comment: `WHERE dept_no = (SELECT ...)`

Comment: How much less complicated can you get than this in joins?

Comment: Probably `select dept_name from departments as d join dept_emp de using(dept_no) where de.emp_no = ?` would do it for you.. not sure about `previously grabbed dept_no` though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use , if evey employee has on one department

```
"SELECT dept_name FROM departments WHERE dept_no = (SELECT dept_no FROM dept_emp WHERE emp_no = ?)"
```

Or if there could be more than one

```
"SELECT dept_name FROM departments WHERE dept_no IN (SELECT dept_no FROM dept_emp WHERE emp_no = ?)"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you I had no idea that you could write another select statement inside the dept_no = portion. This will help me so much with future sql